# How do I achieve this gradient effect on type in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, gradient

I'm trying to achieve the gradient effect shown in the below examples on each letter of the type I'm using in a logo design. I don't really know what this style is called, so I can't effectively look for tutorials regarding how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: Bibliotheque Forum Meyrin Logo]
[image: Flutterfly Logo]
[image: DJ Loop Logo]

Comment: Illustrator CS6 will have gradient strokes and variable-width strokes which will probably be a good way to apply these sort of effects to type. It'll be one to be careful with though - adding regular strokes to text can easily look awful, so adding fancy strokes will need even more delicate care.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're just careful applications of gradient fills and/or meshes to give a depth effect.

Not everything has a specific term for which complete tutorials can be found.

I would advise just trying to recreate these logos and come back when you hit a specific problem.

Answer (score 10):

One good, quick, highly flexible and non-obvious way of getting effects like the first one would be to create a gradient-like blend object from a few thick-stroke lines (see below), make a new pattern brush from it using the brushes panel, curve a path or paths into the right shape, and apply the brush to the paths. Here's an example:

[image: OMG]

The original blended object is top left, the three elements used to make the blend copied and released top right. Note it has to be a blend not a gradient fill since illustrator can't use gradient fills in brushes.

They almost certainly didn't use this technique. But it's a good one :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find something similar on this link. Although this is in solid colors you should be able to get that effect by adding gradients.

http://abduzeedo.com/creating-crazy-cool-logo

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is play with the gradient options and angle.

Just play with those two and I'm sure you will get the same output

Answer (score 0):

I believe the techniques you're after are similar to this post: [How to make these color effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/how-to-make-these-color-effects)

The simple answer, in either Illustrator or Photoshop, is that they're just carefully placed gradients within the shapes. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I think the crux in this question is how the gradients follow the shape, instead of just overlapping the picture/shape as a whole from one side to another.